# Replacing regex matches in one file with lines from another file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to replace lines that match the regex `=> '.*',` in one file with lines from another file.

Two example files.

File 1:

```
    'text_clear' => 'Clear',
    'text_search' => 'Search',
    'text_enabled' => 'Enabled',
```

File 2:

```
emptied
lost
turned off
```

I'm trying to run a linux command using awk/sed/grep to create a third file that would output

File 3:

```
    'text_clear' => 'emptied',
    'text_search' => 'lost',
    'text_enabled' => 'turned off',
```

I've been successful in extracting what I want to edit a python script, but if possible I want to just use a linux command to do both.

I've been racking my head over this for 3 hours now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will you at any point need to insert text such as `That's all` or replace such text, i.e. text that contains single quotes? What about text that contains newlines?

Comment: Can you please clarify one more point? Do all lines in file1 necessarily match? If not, it would have been a nice idea to provide a line that does not match.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`code.awk`**:

```c
BEGIN{j=1}
NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}
sub(/=> '.*',$/,"=> '"a[j]"',"){++j}
1
```

```
awk -f code.awk file2 file1 > file3
```

Line by line **explanation**:

- Initialize `j=1`.
- Put each line of `file2` in the array `a`.
- In `file1`, for each line, try to substitute a string matching the `=> '.*',$` regex by the concatenation of `=> '` `a[j]` `',`. If the substitution occurred, increment `j`.
- Print the line.

```
$ cat file3
    'text_clear' => 'emptied',
    'text_search' => 'lost',
    'text_enabled' => 'turned off',
```

Comment: I am curious: Why use "manual" counters `i` and `j` instead of simply `FNR` for both files?

Comment: @AdminBee Well noted! `i` could be `NR` indeed, I didn't notice it when writing. But not `j` if we assume that there can be lines that do not match in file1. I'm assuming that is possible from the 1st sentence of the question.

Comment: Hm you are right; the sentence can be interpreted like that ...

Comment: Complaint about style: you're allowed to use whitespace in your awk code.

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry about that, I don't like extra whitespace but I do have the impression that they are encouradged by many languages style guides. I'll try to keep that in mind in my future posts.

Answer (score 4):

Another awk approach, using `match` and `substr`:

```
$ awk -v pat="'[^']*'" -v q="'" -v file2='File2' '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS=" => "}
  match($2,pat) && ((getline str < file2) > 0) {
    $2 = substr($2,1,RSTART-1) q str q substr($2,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  1
' File1
    'text_clear' => 'emptied',
    'text_search' => 'lost',
    'text_enabled' => 'turned off',
```

Comment: A GNU awk variation of this answer: `gawk -v patt="(.* => ')[^']+('.*)" -v file2="File2" 'match($0, patt, m) && (getline str < file2) > 0 {$0 = m[1] str m[2]} 1' File1`

Comment: @glennjackman yeah that's nice thanks - tbh I hesitated about posting my answer because of the ugliness of dealing with quoting the replacement text (which your variant avoids cleanly)

Answer (score 3):

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F"'" -v OFS="'" '(getline line < "file2")==1{$4=line} 1' file1
    'text_clear' => 'emptied',
    'text_search' => 'lost',
    'text_enabled' => 'turned off',
```

This relies on the fact that each input line has 2 single quote characters before the field to be replaced.

If you want to replace only lines matching the `=> '.*',` regex, then you can use:

```
awk -F"'" -v OFS="'" '/=> \x27.*\x27,/ && (getline line < "file2")==1{$4=line} 1' file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise solution that uses `paste` and `sed`:

```
$ cat file1
    'text_clear' => 'Clear',
    'text_search' => 'Search',
    'text_enabled' => 'Enabled',
```

```
$ cat file2
emptied
lost
turned off
```

```
$ paste file1 file2 | sed 's/=> \'.*\',\t\(.*\)/=> \'\1\',/'
    'text_clear' => 'emptied',
    'text_search' => 'lost',
    'text_enabled' => 'turned off',
```